# CSS column-rule responsive bug

Tags: html, css, css-multicolumn-layout

I'm trying a 3-column layout using CSS, and would like to have a vertical rule separating the columns. This example inside the iframe is what I'm looking for and seems to work perfect:
http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/03/how-to-use-css3-columns/

The problem is when the source html is removed from the iframe, the rule becomes misplaced when the window is resized:
http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads7/how-to-use-css3-columns/demo.html

This happens in Chrome. Am I missing something? Or is there a workaround this?

```
.cols3 {
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
        -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid #000;

        -moz-column-count: 3;
        -moz-column-gap: 20px;
        -moz-column-rule: 1px solid #000;

        column-count: 3;
        column-gap: 20px;
        column-rule: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It will become mis shapen most likely because you have px rather than %, meaning that that doesn't change over various browsers. Also you are trying to do a 2 column system and your code is saying 3 so you need to change that aswell. Other than that I don't know any other fixes without seeing the rest of your code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I meant 3 column, that is not the issue. Already edited the question.